# How do I catch an input that doesn't match my enum parameters

Tags: c#, enums, try-catch

I have here a way of entering in the day of the week, but if I enter in a number value that is not 1-7 the program simply concludes.  I want to have a way to trigger the catch.

```
        namespace DaysOfTheWeek
{
class Program
{
    public enum EDay
    {
        Monday,
        Tuesday,
        Wednesday,
        Thursday,
        Friday,
        Saturday,
        Sunday,
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello!  A week has 7 days!  What day of this week is it?");
            EDay pickDay = (EDay)Enum.Parse(typeof(EDay), Console.ReadLine(), true);
            Console.WriteLine("The day you picked was {0}", pickDay - 1);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Please enter an actual numerical day of the week.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: `Enum.TryParse`...............

Comment: Numbers can be cast to an enum even when no field in the enum has that integral value (assuming they are in range of the underlying type, usually `int`). For example, `(EDay)15` is valid, though `ToString()` would return "15" and not the name of an enum field. You can check if the number corresponds to an actual Enumerated constant using `Enum.IsDefined` as one of the answers points out. Also, there's a `DayOfWeek` enum in the framework already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll likely want to read what they have input first before converting it into your enum.

Here is a simple example:

```
try
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello!  A week has 7 days!  What day of this week is it?");
    var dayEntered = Console.ReadLine();
    int dayInt;
    bool success = int.TryParse(dayEntered, dayInt);
    if(!success || dayInt < (int)EDay.Monday || dayInt > (int)EDay.Sunday)
    {
        //either throw a new exception to go into your catch block or just have logic here.
    }
    EDay pickDay = (EDay)dayInt;
    Console.WriteLine("The day you picked was {0}", pickDay - 1);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter an actual numerical day of the week.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`IsDefined()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined.aspx) like

```
if(Enum.IsDefined(typeof(EDay), Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `int.Parse` if the input is expected to be "numerical". And, `int.TryParse` will help you catch no-numerical input:

```
var input = Console.ReadLine();
if (int.TryParse(input, out var value))
{
    if (1 <= value && value <= 7)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The day you picked was {0}", (EDay)value - 1);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("PLease enter an number between 1 - 7");
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter an actual numerical day of the week.");
}
```

You can also use `Enum.TryParse` if you also want to accept input like "monday" with addition to the numerical value. Just make sure to change this line if you want `1` to map to `Monday`:

```
Monday = 1,
```

You can also use `(EDay)value` directly if you made the above change for the `int.TryParse` solution.